# Angular mat-form-field asks for "must contain a MatFormFieldControl", but it is a display-only text box

Tags: angular, forms, mat, form-control, mat-form-field

I am trying to put some messages into a text box, and want to utilize mat-form-field's versatility. The box is display only, which means it does not accept input. So I have:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width:2400px">
    <mat-label>Some messages from somewhere</mat-label>
    <textarea cdkTextareaAutosize  cdkAutosizeMinRows="6" [formControl]="some_message"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in TS file:

```
some_message=new FormControl();
```

The problem is:Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.This is puzzling as I provided a control here. I also tried this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width:2400px">
    <mat-label>Some messages from somewhere</mat-label>
    <textarea cdkTextareaAutosize  cdkAutosizeMinRows="6">"some_message"</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Obviously this fails too. If I added MatInput, then this will pass. What's the catch here?

Comment: `MatFormField` is looking for an input inside it but can't find any. Use the appropriate material directive in the textarea and it should work fine

Comment: You need to import =>  MatFormField, ReactiveFormsModule, CdkTextareaAutosize, MatInput,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that I have to add matInput, but meanwhile disable the textbox to prevent any user input:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width:2400px">
    <mat-label>Some messages from somewhere</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput cdkTextareaAutosize  cdkAutosizeMinRows="6" 
    [formControl]="some_message" [disabled]="true"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yout have missed to add matInput in Controls.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width:2400px">
    <mat-label>Some messages from somewhere</mat-label>
    <textarea cdkTextareaAutosize matInput  cdkAutosizeMinRows="6">"some_message"</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I don't want this text box accepting input. But it is close my solution.

Comment: Add Readonly attribute to input.

<textarea cdkTextareaAutosize matInput  cdkAutosizeMinRows="6" readonly>"some_message"</textarea>